# Blazor WebAssembly - child component doesn't refresh

Tags: .net-core, blazor, single-page-application, blazor-webassembly, .net-6.0

Can someone tell me why child component doesn't refresh in my case? (There is no error)
I also tried to load it as DynamicComponent, it triggered the button but also nothing happen with no error.

Thank you.

```
<div id="StackOfCards">
    @while (a < 52)
    {
        b = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor(c / 4));
        lpx = 40 + (b * 0.1) + "%";
        tpx = 41 + (b * 0.1) + "%";
        <div class="cards" style="left: @lpx; top: @tpx; z-index: @a;"></div>
        c--;
        a++;
    }
</div>
<button id="btnNewGame" @onclick="NewGame" style="top: 54%;left: 52%;position: absolute;">New game</button>

@code {
    decimal a = 0;
    int b = 0;
    decimal c = 52;
    string lpx = "";
    string tpx = "";

    public void NewGame()
    {
        a = 0;
        b = 5;
        c = 52;
        StateHasChanged();
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you expecting to happen?

Comment: refresh/ regenerate it.

Comment: Yes, but what do you think will change - the NewGame method doesn't change anything that would affect the output?

Comment: @MisterMagoo it does I think: b changes to 5, which affect lpx

Comment: Except the very first thing you do is reset b : `b = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor(c / 4));`

Comment: i removed b and but it directly as 40 + (Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor(c / 4)) * 0.1) + "%"
still don't work

Comment: But your code in NewGame still doesn't change anything - a is still 0 and c is still 52. Again - what do you expect to change exactly?

Comment: well i did like you mention but still the same. I expected it will render the child component (StackOfCards) on click "NewGame"

Answer (score 0):

Probably because b is an int and 0.1 times 5 is integer 0. Change b to 20 and it will work. Replace b with double or float.

Answer (score 0):

See the below code for a slightly modified version of your code.

Changes:

1. There's a local loop copy of `a` called `locala` to fix the value within the loop.
2. I've added some output to the div within the loop.
3. I've modified the button click event handler to async and added a delay to show that redraw is really happening.
4. Moved the button to the top of the page - for convenience in the demo.

```
@page "/"
<button class="btn btn-success" @onclick="NewGame">New game</button>
<div id="StackOfCards">
    @while (a < 52)
    {
        var locala = a;
        b = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor(c / 4));
        lpx = 40 + (b * 0.1) + "%";
        tpx = 41 + (b * 0.1) + "%";
        <div class="cards" style="left: @lpx; top: @tpx; z-index: @a;">card @locala</div>
        c--;
        a++;
    }
</div>

@code {
    decimal a = 0;
    int b = 0;
    decimal c = 52;
    string lpx = "";
    string tpx = "";

    public async Task NewGame()
    {
        a = 52;
        await Task.Delay(2000);
        a = 0;
        b = 5;
        c = 52;
    }
```